# How to zoom In and zoom out single image in SKSpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Is Spritekit provide any build in function to Single image zoom In and Zoom out in Swift? I am working on a game where i want to give +Star animation on award winning. When I gain point a +Star animation. Is SpriteKit Swift provide any build in function or method to zoom a single image?

```
var textZoom = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Snowball") 
textZoom.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
textZoom.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*0.10, self.frame.size.height*0.20)
textZoom.zPosition = 26.0
self.addChild(textZoom)
```

Comment: Please elaborate and show what you have tried so far. Furthermore, explain a bit more how you are currently showing the image in the scene. I expect using an SKSpriteNode?

Comment: yes I am using SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for SKAction.

```
let zoomIn = SKAction.scaleBy(2.25, duration: 1)
sprite.runAction(zoomIn)
```

You can also combine actions, using the `sequence([SKAction])` method of SKAction.

```
let zoomInZoomOut = SKAction.sequence([zoomIn, zoomIn.reversedAction()])
sprite.runAction(zoomInZoomOut)
```

Since you appear to be rather new to the topic, I suggest reading through Apple's [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html). At the very least, I recommend reading the first chapters to get a feel for the framework.

Comment: I am already using this one also. but it's not solve my problem. Thanks for the the Sprite Kit Programming Guide.

Comment: Please expand your question to explain how this does not solve your problem. Since SKAction is the simplest and designated way to animate, I suppose you are looking for a specific effect?

Comment: @Raksha this is the correct way to zoom in or zoom out an image, CloakedEddy answer correctly to your question. If you not solve your problem correct your question and explain better your issue.

Comment: yes i am implement same functionality. but its not work properly!